# How to control an application running in the background?

Tags: python

So imagine an program, it has a UI and key bindings to do a specific task. I did not make it and the only way I interact with it is via keyboard and mouse. I want to automate the job without giving up my time as currently the window has to be open and the mouse/keyboard is doing things and I cannot use my PC. It would be best if it was in Python or be able to interact with my Python script in some way e.g. reading inputs from file or something.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know of some APIs exposed by the tool, i am not sure if you can get any non-blocking action done on this. In professional Robotic Process Automation platforms, they have an option to run this in the background by pushing the work to another server. You can probably try running this in a Virtual Machine or on another machine so that your window doesn't get blocked by the automation and you don't have to lose time.